# iText -Duplicate Fields Appear on last page

Tags: itext

I am adding fields to an existing PDF using iText 7.NET. (7.1.16)   When they are added, I wind up with a duplicate of every field on the last page.  For example, in a two page document, with the below code, a second field with the same name, Field1 and red border will appear on page two, in the same position. New to iText7, guidance appreciated, Thank You

```
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
                PdfDocument pdf2 = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(outputFile));
                PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf2, true);
                PdfFormField tf = PdfTextFormField.CreateText(
                    pdf2, new Rectangle(1, 20, 30, 40), "Field1", "");
                tf.SetPage(1);
                tf.SetBorderColor(ColorConstants.RED);
                tf.SetBorderWidth(2);
                form.AddField(tf);
                pdf2.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the help for the non-overloaded version of AddField(), without passing a PdfPage parameter  mentions that it adds it to the last page of the document.  I suppose the SetPage() on the field just results on it also being on the specified page.